# Swift 3 Expression was too complex to solve in reasonable amount of time! Really?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

I have the following statement that took xcode almost 10 minutes of build time to figure out that it's complex:

```
print(String(format: "%.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f %.7f",
    self.volatileDataModel.at, self.volatileDataModel.ax, self.volatileDataModel.ay, self.volatileDataModel.az,
    self.volatileDataModel.gt, self.volatileDataModel.gx, self.volatileDataModel.gy, self.volatileDataModel.gz,
    self.volatileDataModel.mt, self.volatileDataModel.mx, self.volatileDataModel.my, self.volatileDataModel.mz,
    self.volatileDataModel.pt, self.volatileDataModel.px, self.volatileDataModel.py, self.volatileDataModel.pz,
    self.volatileDataModel.ph, self.volatileDataModel.pv
));
```

Is that really so complex? How to make it simpler than?

Comment: Its an Xcode problem. You can't do anything.

Comment: Maybe divide it to multiple strings then create an array and print that array ?

Comment: What's the type of `self.volatileDataModel.at` and others, Double?

Comment: yes all are doubles

Comment: Can you paste the whole example? Because in my playground it does compile fine.